# how to select columns as rows in ms access query?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a table as shown below.My question is:How can I convert columns into rows? I'm using Microsoft Access Query.

columns my table is:

```
station and Driver
and value is:  

Station --> Driver

A ----------> john

B ----------> Jack 

C ----------> Michael

B ----------> Noah

B ----------> Ryan

C ----------> Oliver
```

I need op like below

```
Station:-- A ------- B ------- C

         john       Jack    Michael
                    Noah    Oliver
                    Ryan
```

Every suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I do not think that this is possible without VBA, given the input. What exactly are the columns in the table?

Comment: Agree with Fionnuala.  You can use a Pivot Table (let the Query Wizard guide you), but it isn't straightforward.

Comment: how about crosstab query in access?

Comment: @krishKM Did you try a crosstab with the input? It will not work. This has already been discussed in a deleted answer.

Comment: @Fionnuala: something like... http://puu.sh/bi52A/3430dd885b.png

Comment: @krishKM Yes, that is a crosstab, it is not the required output from the OP.